# name 'spark_write_parquet' is not defined - error while writing parquet file in python/databricks/spark

Tags: python, parquet

I am getting below error while writing parquet file
name 'spark_write_parquet' is not defined

Do I need to import anything to make this command defined?
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no function called `spark_write_parquet`! It's always good to at least refer to the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#generic-loadsave-functions) and the [API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet) first!

```
df.select("name", "age").write.save("namesAndAges.parquet", format="parquet")
```

OR

```
df.write.parquet(os.path.join(tempfile.mkdtemp(), 'data'))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got this code from here at stackflow. and could not find right syntax..thanks a lot for your help!